# How to initialize a keytab in docker?

Tags: docker, kerberos, keytab

I have a krb5.conf file. I created a keytab and checked it as expalined [here](http://www.itadmintools.com/2011/07/creating-kerberos-keytab-files.html).

In docker file I added all of it to the container

```
FROM java:8

ADD krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
ADD evkuzmin.keytab /etc/evkuzmin.keytab
ADD scripts/ /opt/scripts/

ADD report.jar report.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch report.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://audpro_mongo/report","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/report.jar","/opt/scripts/init-keytab.sh"]
```

And tried to initialize it in init-keytab.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
kinit EvKuzmin@REALM -k -t /etc/evkuzmin.keytab
```

But every time I try to access the secured cluster, I get Unauthorized error. And when I check my keytab with

```
klist -k evkuzmin.keytab
```

I get evkuzmin.keytab not found.

Why?

I use Oracle virtual box and docker quickstrat terminal to test everything localy. Keytab was generated on the server and copied into the project on local machine.

EDIT

I checked files in the image using

```
docker run -it --entrypoint sh <image-name>
```

they are present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to initialize it. I managed to run it. You can find how I did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959815/docker-image-on-secured-cluster-authenticationexception-unauthorized/46055974#46055974).

EDIT

Also, I found this snippet

```
CMD kinit -kt $HOME/$USER.keytab $USER && ${PROJECT_DIR}/oozie/${PROJECT_NAME}/start.sh
```

which is supposed to initialize the keytab from dockerfile. Didn't test it, so don't know how it'll work with spring. This will start a oozie coordinator with kerberos credentials.

Comment: Nice job. Please self-accept your own answer. This will help better signpost the question to people searching about this problem on Google.